# differences in SPARQL syntax

Tags: sparql

I am wondering if these these two queries produce the same output. 
Lets imagine that I have two RDF Named Graphs of data I've collected, and prefix is shop: 
I want to write a SPARQL query, which finds out which customers prefer which meal, and the output should be human readable

a)

```
PREFIX shop: <"http://example.org/shop">
SELECT ?customerName ?mealName
FROM <Customers.rdf>
FROM <Meals.rdf>
WHERE
{
?customer shop:prefersMeal ?meal .
?meal shop:mealName ?mealName .
?customer shop:customerName ?customerName
}
```

b)

```
PREFIX shop: <"http://example.org/shop">
SELECT ?customerName ?mealName
FROM <Customers.rdf>
FROM <Meals.rdf>
WHERE
{
?x shop:prefersMeal ?meal .
?y shop:mealName ?mealName .
?z shop:customerName ?customerName
}
```

I am trying to figure out the differences, but it looks complicated when you don't have anywhere to practice.

Comment: what do you mean you don't have anywhere to practice? It's really simple to download and install a simple triple store and try a few SPARQL queries. For example, see the [install instructions for RDF4J Server](http://rdf4j.org/doc/rdf4j-server-workbench-and-console/installing-rdf4j-server-and-rdf4j-workbench/).

Comment: The difference becomes quite obvious when you think of both queries as a graph, i.e. draw an edge for each triple pattern with the nodes being subject and object and the edge label being the predicate.

Answer (score 4):

These two queries are not identical.

In the first query, you are reusing the variables `?meal` and `?customer` from your first triple pattern in your second and third triple  pattern. In this query, you are saying: *"give me a customer who prefers a meal, and that same meal must have a name, and that same customer must have a name."*

In the second query, you are using new variables `?y` and `?z` in the second and third clause. What this query says is: *"give me a customer who prefers a meal, and give me the name of some meal, and give me the name of some customer".* You do not enforce that the names you retrieve are for the same customer/meal, so you will get random customer / meal combinations back, rather than the actual preferred meal for each customer.

Comment: are you saying that if I change the ?z with ?x it will force the CustumerName with prefersMeal (like binding costumer name with prefered meal) and than the results of both query's will be same (they will produce the same output?) . I'm using Windows and looking something for windows for sparql.

Comment: You will _also_ need to replace `?y` with `?meal` (or `?meal` with `?y` if you prefer). And RDF4J runs fine on Windows. But if you want something different do a quick google search, there's loads of options.